# Call DynamoDb scan recursively when Promisified

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need to get some data from DynamoDb, using the `scan()` method. I have implemented some basic pagination by calling my function recursively `n` number of times to get the correct `page`.

Currently, I call my function and inside the `scan()` callback, if the data can be send back, I use the handler callback to return the data.

CURRENT CODE

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const TABLE_NAME = process.env.TABLE_NAME
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 500
const DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER = 1

const self = {
    handler: (event, context, callback) => {
        const {pageNumber, pageSize} = event.queryStringParameters ? event.queryStringParameters : {pageNumber: DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER, pageSize: DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE}

        const params = {
            TableName: ORGANISATION_TYPES_TABLE_NAME,
            Limit: pageSize ? pageSize : DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
        }

        return self.scan(params, pageNumber, 1, callback)

    },
    scan: (params, pageNumber, pageCount, callback) => {
        docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(null, {
                    statusCode: 500,
                    body: JSON.stringify(err)
                })
            };

            if (data.LastEvaluatedKey && pageCount < pageNumber) {
                pageCount += 1
                params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey
                self.scan(params, pageNumber, pageCount, callback)
            } else {
                callback(null, {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
            }
            
        })
    }
}

module.exports = self
```

The above code does work, allowing me to specify a `pageSize` and `pageNumber` query parameter.

However, I want to Promisify `self.scan`.

I tried the following, but it results in the `response` being undefined

DESIRED CODE

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const ORGANISATION_TYPES_TABLE_NAME = process.env.ORGANISATION_TYPES_TABLE_NAME
const DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 500
const DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER = 1

const self = {
    handler: (event, context, callback) => {
        const {pageNumber, pageSize} = event.queryStringParameters ? event.queryStringParameters : {pageNumber: DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER, pageSize: DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE}

        const params = {
            TableName: ORGANISATION_TYPES_TABLE_NAME,
            Limit: pageSize ? pageSize : DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
        }

        return self.scan(params, pageNumber, 1).then((response) => {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(response)
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify(err)
            })
        })

    },
    scan: (params, pageNumber, pageCount) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                };

                if (data.LastEvaluatedKey && pageCount < pageNumber) {
                    pageCount += 1
                    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey
                    self.scan(params, pageNumber, pageCount, callback)
                } else {
                    resolve(data)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = self
```

I also tried just doing `return Promise.resolve(data)` inside the `docClient.scan()` callback, but that doesn't work either. It's as if promises cannot be resolved inside a callback?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently helped someone with this problem, there's actually quite an elegant solution that we hit upon that uses the `hasNextPage` property on the response you get from the SDK. The key is to have your recursive function pass an array that holds your results through the recursive calls and just `concat` until you run out of pages and then just return the array.

```
const scan = async params => {
  function scanRec(promise, xs) {
    return promise
        .then(async result => {
            const response = result.$response;
            const items = xs.concat(result.Items);
            response.hasNextPage() ? scanRec(response.nextPage().promise(), items) : items
        })
}

  return scanRec(docClient.query(params).promise(), []);
}
```

You'd then use the function in the normal way:

```
const params = { /** params **/ };

scan(params).then(x => {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Promises and esp aysnc/await. Could you please explain how I use the code above?

Comment: you don't actually need the `async` bit, it's just a habit i've got in to let others know the function is asynchronous. i would advise learning how promises and async/await work before you continue any further. there is a wealth of information online, it will benefit you greatly in the long run.

Comment: I've added a small section about how to use the function.